# Do graph_tool have Communities Louvain algorithm implementation in?

Tags: graph, graph-tool

I'm working on code translating from Networkx to Igraph. This code use community detection based on  [Louvain Community detection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_method). I din't find it on graph_tool documentation, do someone know if it exist?
I readed the documentation of graph tool library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the FAQ: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-perform-modularity-maximization-with-graph-tool

I quote the text below:

> Is it possible to perform modularity maximization with graph-tool?
>
> It is in fact possible to perform modularity maximization with
> graph-tool. For that you need to use the `ModularityState` object
> instead of `BlockState`, as documented in the
> section Inferring modular network structure, e.g.

```py
g = gt.collection.data["football"]

state = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(g, state=gt.ModularityState)
```

However, please note the following admonition:

> **Danger: Using modularity maximization is almost always a terrible idea.**
>
> Modularity maximization is a substantially inferior method to the
> inference-based ones that are implemented in graph-tool, since it does
> not possess any kind of statistical regularization. Among many other
> problems, the method tends to massively overfit empirical data.
>
> For a more detailed explanation see “[Modularity maximization
> considered harmful](https://skewed.de/tiago/blog/modularity-harmful)”, as well as [[peixoto-descriptive-2021]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.00183).
>
> Do not use this approach in the analysis of networks without
> understanding the consequences. This algorithm is included only for
> comparison purposes. In general, the inference-based approaches based
> on `BlockState`, `NestedBlockState`, and `PPBlockState` should be
> universally preferred.